# How do i find bloburl with shared access token expired?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

i have written this below code to get the blob url with cache expiry token, actually have set 2 hours to expire the blob url,

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
           CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                         CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blobname");
            //Create an ad-hoc Shared Access Policy with read permissions which will expire in 2 hours
            SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
            };

            SharedAccessBlobHeaders headers = new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
            {
                ContentDisposition = string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", "blobname"),
            };
            var sasToken = blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, headers);
            blobUrl = blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasToken;
```

using this above code i get the blob url with valid expiry token, now i want to check blob url is valid or not in one client application.
I tried web request and http client approach by passing the URL and get the response status code. if the response code is 404 then I assuming the URL is expired if not the URL is still valid,but this approach taking more time.

Please suggest me any other way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running code very similar to yours, and I am getting a 403 error, which is actually what is expected in this case. Based on your question, I am not sure whether the 403 is more helpful to you than the 404. Here is code running in a console application that returns a 403:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string blobUrl = CreateSAS();
        CheckSAS(blobUrl);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //This method returns a reference to the blob with the SAS, and attempts to read it.
    static void CheckSAS(string blobUrl)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(blobUrl));

        //If the DownloadText() method is run within the two minute period that the SAS is valid, it succeeds.
        //If it is run after the SAS has expired, it returns a 403 error.
        //Sleep for 3 minutes to trigger the error.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(180000);
        Console.WriteLine(blob.DownloadText());
    }

    //This method creates the SAS on the blob.
    static string CreateSAS()
    {
        string containerName = "forum-test";
        string blobName = "blobname";
        string blobUrl = "";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName + DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        blockBlob.UploadText("Blob for forum test");

        //Create an ad-hoc Shared Access Policy with read permissions which will expire in 2 hours
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2),
        };

        SharedAccessBlobHeaders headers = new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
        {
            ContentDisposition = string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", blobName),
        };
        var sasToken = blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, headers);
        blobUrl = blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasToken;

        return blobUrl;
    }
}
```

There are cases in which SAS failures do return a 404, which can create problems for troubleshooting operations using SAS. The Azure Storage team is aware of this issue and in future releases SAS failures may return a 403 instead. For help troubleshooting a 404 error, see http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting/#SAS-authorization-issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same issue a few days back. I was actually expecting storage service to return a 403 error code when the SAS token has expired but storage service returns 404 error.

Given that we don't have any other option, the way you're doing it is the only viable way but it is still not correct because you could get 404 error if the blob is not present in the storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can parse "se" argument from the generated SAS, which means expiry time, e.g. "se=2013-04-30T02%3A23%3A26Z". However, since the server time might not be the same as client time, the solution may be unstable.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

You're using UTC time for `SharedAccessExpiryTime` (see "Expiry Time" in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1#parameters-common-to-account-sas-and-service-sas-tokens).

The expiry time then is registered under the `se` claim in the token the value of which can be checked against current UTC time on the client side before actually using the token. This way you'd save yourself from making an extra call to the Blob storage only to find out whether the token is expired.